# Android 6.0.1: Can we fetch Emoji Icons programmatically

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have updated the `nexus` to `Marshmallow 6.0.1` and wondering if we can fetch `Emoji icons` programmatically if we want to. Anybody know if we can fetch it or not?